# Page visibility Api

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use code from this site http://www.samdutton.com/pageVisibility/ but my script dont work with active or inactive tab in chrome

I have jquery 2.0 and jquery ui

```
var hidden, visibilityChange; 
if (typeof document.hidden !== "undefined") {
    hidden = "hidden";
    visibilityChange = "visibilitychange";
} else if (typeof document.mozHidden !== "undefined") {
    hidden = "mozHidden";
    visibilityChange = "mozvisibilitychange";
} else if (typeof document.msHidden !== "undefined") {
    hidden = "msHidden";
    visibilityChange = "msvisibilitychange";
} else if (typeof document.webkitHidden !== "undefined") {
    hidden = "webkitHidden";
    visibilityChange = "webkitvisibilitychange";
}

function handleVisibilityChange() {
    if (document.hidden) {
       setInterval(function() { console.log('hidden'); }, 1000);
    } else {
       setInterval(function() { console.log('view'); }, 1000);
    }
}

if (typeof document.addEventListener !== "undefined" || typeof hidden !== "undefined") {
    document.addEventListener(visibilityChange, handleVisibilityChange, false);

}
```

---

The original code

```
var hidden, visibilityChange; 
if (typeof document.hidden !== "undefined") {
    hidden = "hidden";
    visibilityChange = "visibilitychange";
} else if (typeof document.mozHidden !== "undefined") {
    hidden = "mozHidden";
    visibilityChange = "mozvisibilitychange";
} else if (typeof document.msHidden !== "undefined") {
    hidden = "msHidden";
    visibilityChange = "msvisibilitychange";
} else if (typeof document.webkitHidden !== "undefined") {
    hidden = "webkitHidden";
    visibilityChange = "webkitvisibilitychange";
}

function handleVisibilityChange() {
    if (document[hidden]) {
       // code hid
    } else {
       // code normal
    }
}

if (typeof document.addEventListener === "undefined" || typeof hidden === "undefined") {
}
else {
    document.addEventListener(visibilityChange, handleVisibilityChange, false);

}
```

Comment: The variable `hidden` is never used.

Comment: Your `if` statemet should most likely be `if (document[hidden])` and the below `if` statement should have a `&&` instead of a `||`.

Comment: The original source actually uses `document[hidden]` and the other `if` statement is for a _negated_ case.

Comment: Yes i have already test this 2 solution with `document[hidden]` and with `if else` but not work

Comment: Maybe try `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`. For me it works but you probably meant `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (document.hidden)
```

should be

```
if (document[hidden])
```

The first statement means “access the property `hidden` of `document`” while the second means “access the property with the name from the string in the variable `hidden` (which is `hidden` or `mozHidden`, etc.) of `document`”.

Likewise, `document['hidden']` would also be equivalent to the first statement.

Then, in your other `if` statement, before assigning an event listener you need to check whether *both* `addEventListener` ***and*** `hidden` exist or are defined. So

```
if (typeof document.addEventListener !== "undefined" || typeof hidden !== "undefined")
```

should become

```
if (typeof document.addEventListener !== "undefined" && typeof hidden !== "undefined")
```

Then it should work (except it probably should have been `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`).

---

If this still doesn’t work you most likely have a syntactical error somewhere else in your code. I recommend validating your code with [JSHint](http://jshint.com).

Comment: Thanks but not working too look the result [https://jsfiddle.net/HHsxc/309/](https://jsfiddle.net/HHsxc/309/) (change tab for view error) i use `setInterval` because i add ajax request after

Comment: [https://jsfiddle.net/HHsxc/310/](https://jsfiddle.net/HHsxc/310/) i need to change time for `setInterval`

Comment: Hi xufox yes its work with setTimeout or simple innerHTML but what is the solution for repeat à request for à ajax ?

Comment: If you could clarify this and put some of your AJAX code into your original question, maybe someone could help you (you could also open a new question, especially if it has nothing to do with the Page Visibility API).

Comment: I have add `clearInterval()` and all work fine lol ! Thanks for all :)

Comment: @p4c Was the actual issue from the beginning that the `'hidden'` and `'view'` loggings got accumulated and got faster and faster?

Comment: Yes i have add script to jsfiddle without `setInterval`: [https://jsfiddle.net/HHsxc/315/](https://jsfiddle.net/HHsxc/315/) with `setInterval`: [https://jsfiddle.net/HHsxc/316/](https://jsfiddle.net/HHsxc/316/)

Comment: @p4c You could have told us what the _actual_ issue is a bit earlier, you know? Nothing in your question even mentions the accumulation of interval function calls. Normally, such questions are closed as off-topic with the reason “questions seeking debugging help require a clear problem statement with the expected result”, etc. A “doesn’t work” _definitely_ wasn’t enough here.

Comment: yeah sorry guy its my fault i dont view the error com from setInterval :/